# Whats wrong with this SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, datatable

```
db.execSQL("create studentTable "+studentTable+"(Id Integer primary key, Name text, Department text, Marks Integer)");
```

Comment: The command is `create table`, not `create <your table name>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it goes, you need to write only `TABLE` instead of `studentTable` at first than write `TABLENAME`

```
CREATE TABLE studentTable(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   Department     TEXT,
   Marks          INT
);
```

check [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_create_table.htm),

Hope that helps.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "studentTable": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE studentTable studentTable(Id INT PRIMARY KET NOT NULL, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Department TEXT, Marks INT)

Comment: this is my real function

Comment: okay. now what you do is just change to, **CREATE TABLE studentTable(Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Department TEXT, Marks INT);**

Comment: you just need to change studentTable to TABLE because you are creating table so you have to mention what you are creating. as written in my answer

Comment: where have you stuck ?

Comment: please accept as answer so that it wil be helpfull to other users@Amir

Comment: by clicking on right icon on left side of my answer@Amir